# C programming Structures and files

Tags: c

Is there any way to store mobile numbers with starting '0' and having 8 or 9 in c without getting the error invalid 8 or 9 in octal constant?

Comment: I used %d.But the error keeps showing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Kindly show your reseacrh / debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: Nobody can tell you about your error if you don't provide the problem code in your question. Create a [MCVE].

Comment: Yes - you need to learn about *strings*.  HTH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not planning on doing math on a "number", then use a char array, not an int. Just because something looks like an integer doesn't mean your program should treat it as one.

Comment: when using char array you must print them with %s. for creating char array you must use code like `char hello[] = "+989121111111"`